# How to extract a part of a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and I want to extract the first 6 characters of each string and store them in a new list.

I can loop through the list and extract the first 6 characters and append them to a new list.

```
y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    y.append(int(x[i][0:6]))
```

I want to know if there is an elegant one line solution for that. 
I tried the following:

```
y = x[:][0:6]
```

But it returns a list of the first 6 strings.

Comment: check out list comprehensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is.** You can use the following **[list-comprehention.](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-list-comprehension/)**
`newArray = [x[:6] for x in y]`

[Slicing](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-slice/) has the following syntax: `list[start:end:step]`

*Arguments:*

> start - starting integer where the slicing of the object starts
>     stop - integer until which the slicing takes place. The slicing stops at index stop - 1.
>     step - integer value which determines the increment between each index for slicing

*Examples:*

> ```
>     list[start:end] # get items from start to end-1
>     list[start:]    # get items from start to the rest of the list
>     list[:end]      # get items from the beginning to the end-1 ( WHAT YOU WANT )
>     list[:]         # get a copy of the original list
> ```

if the `start` or `end` is `-negative`, it will count from the `end`

> ```
>     list[-1]    # last item
>     list[-2:]   # last two items
>     list[:-2]   # everything except the last two items
>     list[::-1]  # REVERSE the list
> ```

**Demo**:
let's say I have an `array = ["doctorWho","Daleks","Cyborgs","Tardis","SonicSqrewDriver"]`
*and I want to get the `first 3` items.*

```
>>> array[:3] # 0, 1, 2 (.. then it stops)
['doctorWho', 'Daleks', 'Cyborgs']
```

*(or I decided to reverse it):*

```
>>> array[::-1]
['SonicSqrewDriver', 'Tardis', 'Cyborgs', 'Daleks', 'doctorWho']
```

*(now i'd like to get the last item)*

```
>>> array[-1]
'SonicSqrewDriver'
```

*(or last 3 items)*

```
>>> array[-3:]
['Cyborgs', 'Tardis', 'SonicSqrewDriver']
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
y = [z[:6] for z in x]
```

This was the same as this:

```
y = []               # make the list
for z in x:          # loop through the list
    y.append(z[:6])  # add the first 6 letters of the string to y
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
stringList = ['abcdeffadsff', 'afdfsdfdsfsdf', 'fdsfdsfsdf', 'gfhthtgffgf']
newList = [string[:6] for string in stringList]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
ans_list = [ element[:6] for element in list_x ]
```

Comment: read the question carefully: `I want to know if there is an elegant one line solution for that. I tried the following:` `y = x[:][0:6]`. OP is trying to use list comprehention with slicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map for this:

```
list(map(lambda w: int(w[:6]), x))
```

and using `itertools.islice`:

```
list(map(lambda w:list(int(itertools.islice(w, 6))), x))
```