# How to make my code do the opposite of its original purpose

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Reverse cypher code in python and I want to reverse it so that it decodes reversed strings:

Code:

```
message = text.get()

translated = (" ")
i = len(message) - 1

while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1

print(translated)
```

EDIT:

```
message = text.get()

translated = (" ")
i = len(message) - 1

while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1

print(translated)

# Creating a string
s = message
# Encoding the string into bytes
b = s.encode("UTF-8")
# Base32 Encode the bytes
e = base64.b32encode(b)
# Decoding the Base32 bytes to string
s1 = e.decode("UTF-8")
# Printing Base32 encoded string
print(s1)
messagebox.showinfo("Encrypted", s1)

def decrypt():
    base64.b32decode(s1)
    translated[::-1]
```

Above is the whole code with the Encrypt and Decrypt

Comment: This just reverses strings? Just put the reversed string back in, reverse is its own inverse. Also you can do this much more concisely with `reversed = message[::-1]`

Comment: How about you give it a try, and if it doesn't work, post a [MCVE] with your problem? Asking people to write simple code for you without showing any effort is frowned upon.

Comment: Didn`t work (NameError: name 's1' is not defined) , however i have posted the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python slices

```
translated[::-1] # reverses the "translated"
```

e.g if you input "hello" it becomes `olleh` and if u want to reverse it again (decode) all you have to do is use [splicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058945/6212957) `"olleh"[::-1]` which gives `hello`

```
message = input("enter msg: ")
translated = (" ")
i = len(message) - 1
while i >= 0:
    translated = translated + message[i]
    i = i - 1

print("Encoded: ", translated)
print("Decoded: ", translated[::-1]) # decode it back to normal by reversing it
```

Result:

```
Encoded: albalb
Decoded: blabla
```

---

**EDIT (op posted the full code in comments):**

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
#Encryption GUI
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import base64

"""
    You have two functions right? one is `encrypt` and the other is `decrypt`.
    Now variable `e` which contains the encypted msg it only visible to the scope of `encrypt` function.
    Meaning that `decrypt` does not know that it exists at all.
"""

# a global variable to store
# both encrypt and decrypt will be able to see this variable
message = ""

#Sub-Routine
def encrypt():

    # Tell python to find the global variable `message`
    global message

    # get input and reverse it using splice
    # "blabla"[::-1] => "albalb"
    message = text.get()[::-1]

    # Encoding the message into bytes
    message = message.encode("UTF-8")

    # Base32 Encode the bytes
    message = base64.b32encode(message)


    # temporarily decode and print encrpyted msg
    # decoding is to make it human-readable (it's only in this function, won't affect anything else)
    e = message.decode("UTF-8")
    messagebox.showinfo("Encrypted", e)

def decrypt():
    # again, tell python to find the global variable
    # we need it! it contains our secret message
    global message

    # decode message
    message = base64.b32decode(message)

    # finally print it
    print("Decrypted", message[::-1].decode("UTF-8"))


#Main
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x425")
root.title("HORIZON Encryption")
root.resizable(True,True)
root.configure(bg='gray95')

#Frame Heading
frame_heading=Frame(root)
frame_heading.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=30,pady=5)
frame_entry=Frame(root)
frame_entry.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=25,pady=10)

#Labels
Label(frame_heading,text="HORIZON Encryption").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=0,pady=5)
Label(frame_entry,text="Text: ").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

text=Entry(frame_entry,width=15,bg='white')
text.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

#Buttons
encrypt_button=Button(root,text="Encrypt",width=7,command=encrypt)
encrypt_button.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)

decrypt_button=Button(root,text="Decrypt",width=7,command=decrypt)
decrypt_button.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=0,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
msg: test
Encrypted ORZWK5A=
Decrypted test
```

Comment: I edited my code a bit to this :                                                                                   
    def decrypt():
    decoded = base64.b32decode(Text.get())
    decoded[::-1]

Comment: And got this error : TypeError: get() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'index1'

Comment: @Omen Updated my answer, check EDIT

Comment: e = base64.b32decode(e)
    # Printing decoded string
    print("Decrypted", e[::-1].decode("UTF-8"))

Comment: Got this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Comment: what version of python are you using btw? please show what you have done http://pastebin.com

Comment: @Omen Ok I believe you are trying to use variable `e` (which wont be found inside your function because of scope rules). You should pass `e` as an argument over to your function. i.e: if u have `myDecrypter()` u can just modify it like this : `def myDecrypter(e): `

Comment: Added an (e) into the function but got error: TypeError: decrypt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'

Comment: check my edited answer, you e from global scope has to be passed as an argument to your function

Comment: bit confused, please explain how to do this,

Comment: would you send your code http://pastebin.com not sure what you're doing

Comment: Oh i found what's wrong. Give me some time to edit this.

Comment: @Omen Finally, finished. Had some issue with b32decoder. But now it works fine. I will now edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for spending time helping me, it is much appreciated

Comment: @Omen if it worked; please upvote &/ accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

A more compact approach could be:

```
def reverse(mssg):
    return mssg[::-1]

print reverse("hello")
```

**Output:**

`>> "olleh"`