# Extracting string from lists of dictionaries (or generator)

Tags: python-3.x, youtube

I am scraping data with [scrapetube](https://pypi.org/project/scrapetube/) to get the video IDs of all the videos from a YouTube channel. The scrape code returns a generator object which I have converted to a list of dictionaries containting other dictionaries, lists and string. The scraping code works, but here still some [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgjk45ycpay1l49/YouTube%20Scraper%20sample%202021-09-21.txt?dl=0). I am only interested in the string *video Id* --> see picture for illustration purposes[image]

How to iterate through all the video IDs in the string *videoId* and save them in a new variable (list or dataframe) for further processing?

```
import scrapetube

vid = scrapetube.get_channel('UC_zxivooFdvF4uuBosUnJxQ')
type(vid) #generator file 
video = next(vid) #extract values from generator & then convert it
videoL = list(vid) #convert it to a list

#code not working
for item in videoL['videoId']:
    entry = {}
    videoId = item['videoId']
    for i in range(len(videoId)):
        entry.append(int(videoId[i][0:10]))

#error message: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I used code snippet from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058733/how-to-extract-a-part-of-a-list-of-strings) but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: `videoL = list(vid)` now `videoL` is a `list`. In the next line you're accessing it like if it was a dictionary (next time please provide full traceback to avoid the guessing)

Comment: probably a typo: `for item in videoL['videoId']` should be `for item in videoL`

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `video_ids = [item['videoId'] for item in vid]`?

Comment: @Axe319 it is! thanks so much! Neat. I have google around for hours.... Please post it as answer.

Comment: @Simone I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's helpful when you know the terminology so let's go through it step by step.

**What is a generator?**

A generator, like it's name implies, generates values on demand.
Their usefulness in this case is that if you don't want to have all the data in memory, you only iterate over one generated value at a time and only extract what you need.

Consider this:

```
def gen_one_million():
    for i in range(0, 1_000_000):
        yield i

for i in gen_one_million():
    # do something with i
```

Rather than having a million elements in a `list` or some container in memory, you only get one at a time. If you want them all in a `list` it's very easy to do with `list(gen_one_million())` but you're not tied to having them all in memory if you don't need them.

**What is a `list` and how do I use them?**

A `list` in python is a container represented by brackets `[]`. To access elements in a `list` you can index into it `i = my_list[0]` or iterate over it.

```
for i in my_list:
    # do something with i
```

**What is a `dict` and how do I use them?**

A `dict` is a python key/value container type represented by curly braces and a colon between the key and value. `{key: value}`
To access values in a `dict` you can reference the key who's value you want `i = my_dict[key]` where `key` is a string or integer or some other hashable type. You can also iterate over it.

```
for key in my_dict:
    # do something with the key

for value in my_dict.values():
    # do something with the key

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # do something with the key and value
```

**How does my case fit into all this?**

Looking at your sample data it looks like you already have it converted from a generator to a `list`.

```
[
    {
        'videoId': '8vCvSmAIv1s', 
        'thumbnail': {
            'thumbnails': [
                {
                    'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8vCvSmAIv1s/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEbCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDDggBFQAAiEIYAXABwAEG&rs=AOn4CLDn3-yb8BvctGrMxqabxa_nH-UYzQ',
                    'width': 168, 
                    'height': 94}, # etc..
                }
            ]
        }  
    }
]
```

However, since you just need to iterate over it and access the `'videoID'` key in each generated `dict`, there's no reason to convert.
Just iterate directly over the generator and access the key of each generated `dict`.

```
video_ids = []
for item in vid:
    video_ids.append(item['videoId'])
```

Or even better, as a `list` comprehension.

```
video_ids = [item['videoId'] for item in vid]
```

Comment: Great thanks Axe for the detailed answer.